# How can I run code in selenium to execute a function at a specific hour of the day within the python script not cron

Tags: java, python, selenium

I have written a python selenium script to log me into a website.  This website is where I need to book a court at precisely 7am.  I cannot run the script using cron scheduler because that only runs the script and by the time selenium has logged in 7am will have passed. I've tried time() and Webdriverwait but these only allow me to delay hitting a web page button.  I need to synchronise the click of a button at a precise time from within the python script.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be in combination with a cron job.
You can start the cron 1-2 minutes earlier, open the login page and, in your python script, sleep until 7am then just login.

Comment: The only problem with this is there are 10 other people all fingers on the mouse hitting the same webpage button.  I wanted to use the UTC via NTP in  Linux to beat them to it. I guess it would be similar to making that final bid on ebay.  Cron can schedule jobs to the second but that may not be enough.  I know a guy who has done it in Selenium and also create an interrupt and it hits the button at exactly 7am and he beats every single mouse driven members every week.

Comment: There must be a way of synchronising the click() with the system clock (which is getting its time from UTC).

Comment: I have exhausted the internet forums over the last week with no solution to my idea.  I'll have a chat with my mate and when he tells me how he has done it I'll post it on here Stack only.  I really wanted to hack this without asking him though :-(

Comment: The reason Cron is not ideal is that if it's not precisely 7am and Cron launches it half a second before 7am the web page will not process it and I get an error message: courts cannot be booked before 7am!  whilst I am reading that (or in bed as I think Cron is doing the business) everyone will have clicked on their mouse button (yes, they get up that early just to book the courts).  If the python script, launched by Cron, is one second late, then I've also missed my chance as everyone has fingers o the mouse buttons.  Do you see my dilemma?

Comment: BTW, i don't want to get up at 7am at all as I want to use Cron to launch the script but python to synchronise the button being hit at precisely the time I want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119031/how-to-have-loop-sync-with-utc-timer-and-execute-at-every-new-minute.

Comment: I've done it!  The link above was of great help.  The python code of input will execute at precisely the time th new minute starts.  I run the Python script using Cron at 6.59 and Python will wait until it is 7.00am and bang!  the submit button is hit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119031/how-to-have-loop-sync-with-utc-timer-and-execute-at-every-new-minute

Answer (score 0):

I've done it!  The link above was of great help.

The python code of input will execute at precisely the time the new minute starts.  I run the Python script using Cron at 6.59 and Python will wait until it is 7.00am and bang! the submit button is pressed by python and selenium.

My code (really the code above!):

```
    def WaitForNextMinute():
        secs = datetime.utcnow().second
        while secs < 57:
              sleep (57 - secs)
              secs = datetime.utcnow().second
        while datetime.utcnow().second >= 57: 
            sleep (1)


    while True:
        WaitForNextMinute()
        inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("save_booking").click()
```

The thing about Python is the indent rule...annoying!!!